# Joomla construction online but private

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

Anyone know how this is possible. To develop your website (modules and everything but only for me (admin) to be viewable and not to the public yet. I don't want to make it in XAMPP and then re-upload it on the live server. (it has caused some problems in the past)

One way I thought is by restricting website access to my IP only through .htacess would this cause any malfunctions or any problemos?

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Of course, how can this be done? I tried searching within Joomla but didnt find anything. I searched google too but nothing. 
Will this cause any difference in the way the site will behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions to put your Joomla site "offline". Here you go:

http://docs.joomla.org/Taking_the_website_temporarily_offline

Comment: If I put the website down will I have access to the pages/modules, content etc (being logged as administrator)? Does anything change other than the website being private for the public visitors?

Comment: Please note, that Joomla does indeed behave differently when in offline mode, because you have to login first: so the cache is not enabled and more queries are made; also the mootools libraries will be always loaded (they are required for frontend-editing of the articles). If you can live with these (minor) differences, fine. Otherwise you can use an .htaccess and .htpasswd to password-protect the folder and leave the site open.